# Java Swing: JEditor Pane text invisible at highlighting

Tags: java, swing, text, jeditorpane, invisible

We have a problem with our JEditor Pane. When highlighting text in the pane the text gets partly invisible. If we click somewhere in the GUI outside the pane the text gets visible again.
Thats how it should look

[image]

Thats how it looks when the text is marked

[image]

Our project is a debugger for two or more programs.
This is the code to initialize the EditorPane:

```
private void initCodeArea() {
    codePanel = new JPanel();
    listBreakpointLines = new ArrayList<>();

    editor = new JEditorPane();
    editor.setEditorKit(new StyledEditorKit() {
        @Override
        public ViewFactory getViewFactory() {
            return new CustomViewFactory(super.getViewFactory());
        }
    });
    Font font = new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 12);
    editor.setFont(font);

    editor.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                if (e.getX() > 0 && e.getX() < MARGIN_WIDTH_PX) {
                    int height = editor.getFontMetrics(editor.getFont()).getHeight();
                    int lineID = e.getY() / height + 1;
                    if (!listBreakpointLines.contains(lineID)) {
                        listBreakpointLines.add(lineID);
                        controlFacade.createBreakpoint(id, lineID);
                    } else {
                        listBreakpointLines.remove((Integer) lineID);
                        controlFacade.deleteBreakpoint(id, lineID);
                    }
                }
                editor.updateUI();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            mainInterface.saveText();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        }
    });

    codeScrollPane.setViewportView(editor);

    codeScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
    codePanel.add(codeScrollPane);
}
```

This is the method to set the text in the EditorPane:

```
public void setText(String programText) {
    editor.setText(programText);
    listModel.clear();
    variableInspectorList.updateUI();
}
```

The rest of the code can be found in our GitHub repository (dev-Branch):

[GitHub repository](https://github.com/JoanaP1997/PSE/tree/dev)

Comment: The code you've posted give us no hint about the cause of your porblem. So if you want to get answer, please provide a small runnable example ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org)) which demonstrates your issue, so we can also run and debug your code.

Comment: *"The rest of the code can be found in our GitHub repository.."* No thanks. All relevant code (as in, an SSCCE or [mcve]) should be included as an [edit] to the question.

Comment: Don't invoke updateUI() on a component. Swing will automatically repaint the component when you change a property of the component.